# Creating android game

Tags: android

Is it comfortable to write a game for android with imageviews textviews etc. or to write a game using libraries such as libgdx or sth like that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on what your game would look like. If you want to work with sprites and other fancy stuff, you better use the tools that were invented for that (libgdx, ...).
If you just want to make a game which would be a simple quiz, you could do that with the standard android libraries.